# doorbell, chime unit fried after 3 month

Tags: electrical

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Pictures 2]

I have a doorbell with 2 push buttons connected (front door and back door.) 3 months ago the front door button stopped working. I checked the chime box and the coponent for the front door was broken(bar hitting the metal plate doing creating the ring) the other one was ok and back door button working fine).
I replaced the whole unit and it worked well. 
3 months later the front door button stop working again. I tried changing the push button itself but with no result. I checked the chime box and the top part seemed burned (plastic cover has brown stained). The back door button still works.

If the same composent get fried for a second time in 3 months, there must be an electrical problem somewhere but how do I fix it? (I can't afford to buy a new unit every 3 months)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the faulty chme?

Comment: A stuck button will burn out the coil in the chime. If you've replaced the button now, replace the chime again.  Also a seeming weird question, but did you get a new furnace?  In my area, alot of times instead of installing a transformer dedicated to the doorbell, they borrow low voltage power from the furnace. If you got a new furnace that could be impacting your doorbell.

Comment: Hi Tyson,

No, I did not get a new furnace. I will try to install a new door bell again now that I have a new push button. I never noticed that is was stuck, at least not mechanically (We were always able to press it), but I'll try nonetheless for sure.

Comment: Hi ThreePhaseEel,

Comment: Trying to post the pictures but it doesn't seem to work. :-(

Comment: @Nick -- did you get the pictures in? If not, just upload them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post links here

Comment: Yes I finally managed to do it. I hope that helps.